# How to use Twitter gem in Rails?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, twitter, twitter-oauth

I am planning to use the Twitter gem in my app, but I am stuck trying to figure out what an OAUTH token is, and where can get it. Twitter's documentation has been no help to me so far.

```
Twitter.configure do |config|
  config.consumer_key = YOUR_CONSUMER_KEY
  config.consumer_secret = YOUR_CONSUMER_SECRET
  config.oauth_token = YOUR_OAUTH_TOKEN
  config.oauth_token_secret = YOUR_OAUTH_TOKEN_SECRET
end

Twitter.user
```

Can anyone gently explain to me what I need to do in order to set this up correctly to use in my app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should only need the consumer key and consumer secret.  The oauth token and oauth secret are for the non-browser version of the app (I can't remember the actual word) which allows you to have a permanent link to twitter from an account to tweet without authorizing each time.

Answer (score 1):

Go to http://developer.twitter.com/
Register an app (make one up)..
All the authentication information you need will be provided.